# docker compose mongodb container work, but UI can't connect it (timeout)

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, connection

1. docker compose bulid mongodb container and it worked.
2. create db and collection and insert data done.
3. then, get in this container can find those data I mentioned.
   but when I'm using Vscode extensions (MongoDB for VS Code or app : MongoDBCompass or DB extensions)
   they can't connection this container.

this is my yml:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mongo", "--eval", "db.adminCommand('ping')"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
```

mongosh in container:

```
admin> show dbs
JobDB   432.00 KiB << this is my testing db, there're some collections and data
admin   100.00 KiB
config  108.00 KiB
local    72.00 KiB
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                   CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                               NAMES
fb43b9cbfb63   apache/airflow:2.7.3   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (healthy)     8080/tcp                            automation-airflow-triggerer-1
52af82cb0b13   apache/airflow:2.7.3   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (healthy)     0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp              automation-airflow-webserver-1
28f084bff929   apache/airflow:2.7.3   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (healthy)     8080/tcp                            automation-airflow-scheduler-1
da474b892d84   apache/airflow:2.7.3   "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (healthy)     8080/tcp                            automation-airflow-worker-1
e27505eb04e9   redis:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (healthy)     6379/tcp                            automation-redis-1
ee686330e99d   mysql:8.0              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes               33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp   automation-mysqldb-1
d8b4971d9b86   postgres:13            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (healthy)     5432/tcp                            automation-postgres-1
f4ad04c6de18   mongo:latest           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp            automation-mongodb-1
```

docker network ls

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                         DRIVER    SCOPE
f45e66a2be2e   automation_default           bridge    local
```

connect wiht extensions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR1Ld.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb7Jy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq1km.png)

`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' automation-mongodb-1`
bring this container ip is still not connect it wiht UI

then `timeout` and `Authentication failed`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVS1P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSm9U.png)

Comment: the hostname should be localhost or the IP address of the machine, not mongodb.

Comment: but put localhost or IP address of the machine, it's still time out

Comment: `Authentication failed` already means you are on the right track. Did you change the password?

Comment: no, but 27017 is already in use by local MongoDB (there is no password)

Comment: Are you running docker compose on your local machine? Maybe you have to kill your local instance then restart the docker compose. The status of your mongodb container is unhealthy, maybe try printing the logs (`docker logs automation-mongodb-1`)

Comment: Or use a different port instead.

Comment: ok, I know what I've done. fix problem by using different port.

Answer (score 0):

You have timeout error because you try to connect your MongoDB server using unknown URI. You use `mongodb` in your URI which is incorrect. You should do so only when you try to connect your server from other service within the same MongoDB's container network.

As it seems you connect from your host, you need to use this URI: `mongodb://root:example@127.0.0.1:27017`. You can do so because you export port `27017` in your docker compose configuration in your MongoDB service, thus the port is available on your host.